# Run a rake task of rails application through another rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I have two Rails app , I would like to run a rake task of App B by a rake task of App A. So far I have tried it in this way but there is an error like:

```
Don't know how to build task 'environment' (See the list of available tasks with `rake        --tasks`)
```

The rake task of App A is:

```
namespace :daily_all_rake do
 desc 'daily Rake'
  task :daily_rake do
   Bundler.with_clean_env do
  exec("exec >> lib/rake/out.dat && exec 2>> lib/rake/err.dat && 
  cd #{App_B Path} && 
  RAILS_ENV=production BUNDLE_GEMFILE=#{Gemfile of App B} bundle exec rake -f #{Path to Rake File in App B} delete_duplicate_search_object:every_month --trace")
 end
 end
 end
```

Rake task of App B is just a normal rake task. I am curious to know is it possible to do it and if it is possible how can I do this?

Comment: I think you have an error in the way you call the rake task; Try calling the rake task the normal way (from app B's terminal) does it work?

Comment: It works if I call it in a normal way from App B terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `:environment`

Try adding it after `task :daily_rake` like this:

```
namespace :daily_all_rake do
  desc 'daily Rake'
  task :daily_rake => :environment do
    Bundler.with_clean_env do
      exec("exec >> lib/rake/out.dat && exec 2>> lib/rake/err.dat && 
      cd #{App_B Path} && 
      RAILS_ENV=production BUNDLE_GEMFILE=#{Gemfile of App B} bundle exec rake -f #{Path to Rake File in App B} delete_duplicate_search_object:every_month --trace")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried your answer , but still I have the same error.